# Stuttering when navigating to a next.js page with a video in the background

Tags: reactjs, next.js, frontend

I'm building an app with next.js 13, the home page has a video playing in the background. When I try to navigate to the home page using the navbar, I experience a frame drop, which does not happen on other pages that don't have a video in the backgoround.

Here is a sample of how this is implemented in the code:

Video background component:

```
const VideoBackground = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={styles['video-background']}>
      <video preload autoPlay muted loop>
        <source src='/video.mp4' type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Usage:

```
import VideoBackground from './components/VideoBackground'


export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
    <VideoBackground>
    <main className={styles.main}>
      <h1>Main page</h1>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Obcaecati commodi corporis soluta nisi aliquam pariatur hic, illum voluptate omnis mollitia, quas, natus at! Similique dolores accusantium laborum minima repellat! Officiis!</p>
    </main>
    </VideoBackground>
    <p className={styles.content}>
      Lorem ipsum
    </p>
   </div>
  )
}
```

I have tried to optimize the video by compressing it, but it has not helped.

I have tried optimizing the video, or implementing next.js dynamic loading, but because the video loads immediately, it does not help. Adding the preload attribute to the video tag has also not helped.